# Exiting a program without coredump or Segmentation Faults

Tags: c++, exit, terminate, quit

I was wondering if there were some ways to exiting/terminate a program abruptly without causing a `segfault` or `core dump`.

I looked into `terminate()` and `exit()` and `return 0`. They all seem to not work in my project.

```
if(this->board.isComplete())
 {
     Utils::logStream << " complete "<< endl;
     this->board.display();
     exit(0);
     //std::terminate();
     //abort();
     //raise(SIGKILL);
     return true;
}
```

Comment: `exit(0)` should work (for most definitions of work... it depends a bit on whether there're shutdown operations you "need" done) - what happens when you try it?

Comment: @Tony D exit(0) seems to fit my question's requirements. But the program never closes the files it opens.

Comment: @Ben, you may want to clarify. As it stands, your comment makes no sense. Forgetting to release memory does not, in itself, cause segv's.

Comment: @Ben No, I'm not using any, I believe. If I were, how could I delete all the memory?

Comment: I am reading about raise(SIGKILL)'s at the moment. Would this also work like exit(0)?

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal code snippet that demonstrates how you are generating a segfault upon calling `exit(0)`?

Comment: @DavidO The exit(0) works for not providing segfault , I must have done something wrong.

Comment: Additionally, can you explain what environment you are running this code under? Is it Windows? OS X? TI's SYS/BIOS?

Comment: "never closes the files..." - you can read about the cleanup actions performed by [exit here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit)... they include flushing C streams, but *"Stack is not unwound: destructors of variables with automatic storage durations are not called."* so if you've got `fstream`s on the stack you may want to `flush` them before calling down to where the exit takes place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exit()/abort()` and similar functions are usually not the proper way for terminating a C++ program. As you have noticed, they do not run C++ destructors, leaving your file streams open. If you really must use `exit()`, then registering a cleanup function with [`atexit()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atexit/) is a good idea, however, I would strongly recommend that you switch to C++ exceptions instead. With exceptions, destructors are called, and if there is some top level cleanup to be done before termination, you can always catch the exception on `main()`, do the cleanup and then return normally with an error code. This also prevents the code dump.

```
int main()
{
    try 
    {
        // Call methods that might fail and cannot recover.
        // Throw an exception if the error is fatal.
        do_stuff();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        // Return some error code to indicate the 
        // program didn't terminated as it should have.
        return -1;
    }

    // And this would be a normal/successful return.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your method and it works just the way I wanted

Comment: Cool, make sure to "accept" my answer, @flyaboveothers ;)